# Error HH19: Your project is an ESM project (you have "type": "module" set in your package.json) but your Hardhat config file uses the .js extension

Tags: javascript, hardhat, error

```
Error:
Error HH19: Your project is an ESM project (you have "type": "module" set in your package.json) but your Hardhat config file uses the .js extension.

Rename the file to use the .cjs to fix this problem.
```

Renaming the file to .cjs didn't work and couldn't find `"type": "module"` file.

Package.json:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@chainlink/contracts": "^0.8.0",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "1",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers": "^1.0.10",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "^4.0.0",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers": "^2.2.3",
    "@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan": "^3.1.8",
    "@typechain/ethers-v6": "^0.5.1",
    "@typechain/hardhat": "^9.1.0",
    "chai": "^5.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ethers": "5",
    "hardhat": "^2.19.4",
    "hardhat-contract-sizer": "^2.10.0",
    "hardhat-deploy": "^0.11.45",
    "hardhat-gas-reporter": "^1.0.9",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "prettier-plugin-solidity": "^1.3.1",
    "solhint": "^4.0.0",
    "solidity-coverage": "^0.8.5",
    "typechain": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-js": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
|
```

hardhat.config.js:

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox")
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan")
require("hardhat-deploy")
require("hardhat-contract-sizer")
require("dotenv").config()`

`module.exports = {
    solidity: "0.8.7",
}
```

New to javascript/solidity, have been on stuck this for some hours.

I thank you all in advance:).

Comment: Downgrading "chai" from 5.00 to 4.3.7 helped solve the error, i had dependencies that require ES modules and thats why i got the error.

Comment: Hi! I'm happy you found a solution, but instead of leaving it as a comment, please leave it as an answer to the question - it's more likely to help others with the same issue that way. Cheers!

Comment: will do thank you:)

Answer (score 6):

Downgrading "chai" from 5.00 to 4.3.7 helped solve the error, i had dependencies that require ES modules and thats why i got the error.